# How to insert a character after every x amount(10) of characters on Sublime Text? V3.2.2

Tags: sublimetext3

```
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
```

**insert "&B5&" after every 10 characters, becomes to**

```
word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word
```

How can I do that with *Sublime Text 3 or Notepad++ or else*?
What is the regex find and replace suggestions? Or any other useful way to do it

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using regular expresion, here is an example using vscode: `[^.*]{10}` replace all with `$0 "&B5&"`

[image]

output:

```
word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word
```

> note: you can use this regex also for sublime. don't forget to check .* button

[image]

or using php:

```
$input = 'word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word';

$input = preg_replace('#([^.*]{10})#', '$1 "&B5&"', $input);

echo $input;
```

output:

```
word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word word "&B5&"word
```